# Laravel 5.7 select only relationship data without loop through other relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have 3 tables
1) product
2) comment
3) user

one product can have many comments and one comment belongs to one user only.
here is a relationship which I defined for all 3 models.

**1) Product Model**

```php
class product{
     public function comments(){
           return $this->hasMany(Comments::class,'product_id');
     }
}
```

**2) Comments Model**

```php
class comments{

     public function product(){
           return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
     }

     public function user(){
           return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','user_id');
     }
}
```

**3) User Model**

```php
class User{
     public function comment(){
           return $this->belongsTo(Comments::class);
     }
}
```

**I want to get all users who commented on the product. (I know I can do by with() and loop through product and comment but I don't want to loop through all comments, I want all users in an answer without comment data.)**

---

> In short from product id I want all users data who commented on that
>   product (without loop through all comment)

---

Comment: @Iftikharuddin yes it is also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "bypass `comments` relationship", because you don't have direct relation between `product` and `user`, but you can get comments along with their users and then `pluck` all users.

```php
$users = Product::with('comments', 'comments.user')
                ->find(2) // product_id
                ->comments
                ->pluck('user')
                ->unique();
```

You'll get collection of unique `User` models.

Don't forget that `->find()` could return `null`, so you should add corresponding check, in order to avoid getting exception by accessing `->comments` of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
User::whereHas('comment', function ($query) use ($productId) {
        $query->whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($productId) {
            $query->where('products.id', $productId);
        });
    })->get();
```

Comment: OP want it from `productId` not directly from `User` Model

Comment: @jinal I want to get user data from product object only. read whole question.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya I think still you not get my question...
I want all users eloquent object from product Eloquent object only.
Like Product::find(2)->with('users'); bypassing comment relationship

Comment: @jigarhalani but you don't have relation between product and user model

Comment: @JinalSomaiya but I have a relationship between product -> comment and comment -> user so is there any way I can get user directly from the product that is what my question is.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya I know i can loop thorugh comments and get user data. but i want all user data with some easy way. without looping throgh comments.

Comment: @jigarhalani through my query you don't need to looping comments.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya Thanks. Your answer is also correct but I don't want to use query. one upvote for your efforts. :)